# Как в selenium взять текст элемента с пробелами в начале и в конце в c#

Tags: c#, selenium

IWebElement.Text обрезает пробелы в начале и в конце. Как можно этого избежать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться методом getAttribute() как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298400/how-to-get-webelement-text-with-selenium), но это java.

Comment: Спасибо, работает с IWebElement.GetAttribute("textContent")